# How to change text style?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic clickable text with black color, and I want to make another text green, but if I change it, the text that changes in black

How can i do this?

```css
a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="margin-ot"><a href="file:///...index.html">Reviews from past exams</a></p>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You want another text where? You could use a span

Comment: @mplungjan if you change to green then all the text will be green and I need one green and another black

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the element you wanted to be green a specific class, then use that class to style it. Notice that i declared that style below the original style with a class selector next to it to give it the priority.

All of the above is related to [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), [Selector Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). I suggest to take a research about all those CSS concepts which is really important to understand.

Additional, you can wrap the inner text of the black text by a span, then style it the way you want.

```css
a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.green{
 color: green;
}
a span{
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="margin-ot"><a href="file:///...index.html">Reviews from past exams</a></p>
<p class="margin-ot"><a href="file:///...index.html" class="green">Reviews from past exams</a></p>
<p class="margin-ot"><a href="file:///...index.html">Reviews from past<span> exams </span></a></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is confusing, please explain better what exactly you want to achive here.

If you have element with nested ones, then styles from parent also will affect it's children. The cleanest way to set different styling to children elements is to add to it various classes, for example:

```css
.text-green {
  color: green;
}

.text-big {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<p>A paragraph text with <span class="text-green text-big">span element in different color and size</span>.</p>
```